# Deterministic CFL closure Property Homomorphism

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, context-free-languages

I tried to research the following question with no results: Can you find one example where the following holds true:

Let  L = {xxxxxxx} be a deterministic-context-free Language and Let h(...) = xxxxx be a Homomorphism.
Then the Homomorphism on that language L h(L) ist NOT a deterministic-CFG anymore.

Comment: I do not know the answer, but how do you know that there is an example?  Maybe I am misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I made up an example myself 10 minutes after my post. I am going to post it soon.

Comment: @kiltek Accept your answer then also.

Comment: possbile tomorrow

Comment: Welcome to cstheory, a Q&A site for *research-level* questions in *theoretical computer science* (TCS). Your question does not appear to be a research-level question in TCS. Please see the [FAQ] for more information on what is meant by this and suggestions for sites that might welcome your question. Finally, if your question is closed for being out of scope, and you believe you can edit the question to make it a research-level question, please feel free to do so. Closing is not permanent and questions can be reopened, check the [FAQ] for more information.

Comment: Kaveh thanks for your down vote. I hope you can GET IT UP again.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Please post the question to [cs.stackexchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Why is the solution incorrect. explain.

Comment: You have not answered my question.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: What part did you not understand? What a deterministic-CFG is? What determinism in general is? Or something else?

Comment: In [revision 1](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/revisions/11792/1), you claimed that a homomorhpic image of a DCFL is not necessarily DCFL.  At the same time, you asked for an example.  This means that you knew there is an example, yet you did not know an example.  I was wondering how that could happen.  But honestly, I do not want to talk to you anymore after seeing your rude replies to Kaveh and sdcvvc.  This is my last comment in this thread.

Comment: ok, i grant you that, but one thing remains: What is wrong with my example. I think it is a 100% correct.

Comment: Please consider reposting the question on [cs.se] which has a broader scope. ps: I would have migrated the question there however the system does not allow it (it is too old for migration).

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{a^nb^nc^m\mid m,n\ge0\}$, $B=\{a^nb^mc^m\mid m,n\ge 0\}$, and $L=dA \cup B$. Then the homomorphism $h:\{a,b,c,d\}\to\{a,b,c\}$ defined by $h(a)=a$, $h(b)=b$, $h(c)=c$, and $h(d)=\epsilon$ gives $h(L)= A \cup B$ which is not a DCFL.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

Take this Deterministic-CFL L = {$a^{l}b^{m}c^{n}\,|\, m=n$} and take this homomorphism-function:
 
h(a)=b, 
h(b)=b, 
h(c)=c. 
Then this homomorphism on L looks like this $$h(L)=\{{b^{l}b^{m}c^{n}\,|\, m=n}\}$$

Now there is no Deterministc-PDA for this anymore, because the PDA would have to guess the end of the first "package" of b's ($b^{l}$).

Comment: Your language $h(L)$ is deterministic: it is better expressed as $\{b^m c^n\mid m\geq n\}$.  And do please post on cs instead of cstheory for basic questions.